# Overriding Joomla config component

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to override this file in Joomla 3.2:
components > com_config > controller > templates > display.php

Is this possible via standard template overrides? If not, how do I need to go about overriding this file?

Comment: What are you trying to override? What is your ultimate goal? As jonasfh said, you can't just replace this file through a standard override, but you should be able to override the final output.

Answer (score 0):

through standard override it is possible to override views, not controllers. So you should be able to override components/com_config/view/templates/tmpl/default.php, but not files in the controller-folder. It is possible to override other parts of the mvc, outlined [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core), but I have not tried this, and you need to install an extra plugin for this.

Comment: You can override controllers, it's explained on the documentation site.

Comment: Hi @Elin, I didn't know this, and it's not obvious to me in the google search results. Could you provide a link to the docs?

Comment: I put "override joomla controller" in Google and this was the top result
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: OK, @elin, I've seen that link, it's the same I referenced in my answer. But it states at the top, in the notice: "This method only works if you install and enable the 3rd party MVC plugin joomla-override found on github - or provide your own equivalent plugin. It is fine for advanced developers - just be aware that this is not part of Joomla! Core code". So I figured it's probably not part of the joomla core :)

Comment: The core provides you with the ability to override controllers. You need to do the work however. This is a coding site and it is something for coders to do, not end users.